# I want to write a script to copy a file from a directory to another directory and rename it

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I want to write a batch script and ones I double click on it, it should copy a file from a directory to another directory and rename it to be fileX, knowing that there is a file with the same name in the destination directory.

So what I want to do is to remove the already existed fileX and copy the other one instead.

How can I do that, and please comment the script so I can understand.

Comment: If you look at `copy /?` you will see that there is a switch to allow you to overwrite an existing file.  So you don't need to delete the existing file, just copy over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `xcopy` to do it. For example :

```
echo [Copy files]
echo * Create the file xcopy_EXCLUDE.txt in order to ignore some file and/or directory.
echo .au3 > xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo .pspimage >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo \psp\ >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo *   - ignore all .au3 files
echo *   - ignore all .pspimage files
echo *   - ignore the \psp\ directory
echo * The file xcopy_EXCLUDE.txt is created.
echo.
echo * Copy additional files with xcopy.
xcopy "%FOLDER_SRC%" "%FOLDER_OUT%" /E /H /Y /EXCLUDE:xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo * Files and directory are copied.
echo.
echo * Delete xcopy_Exclude.txt.
del xcopy_Exclude.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to look into powershell. Here is the command you would run.

```
# Path is the location to the original file
# Destination is where you want it to go
# -force indicates that it shoud replace a file if it finds it and not prompt you first
Copy-Item -Path "c:\temp\original.txt" -Destination "c:\folder2\filex.txt" -force

# For more help:
Get-Help Copy-Item
```